# Document Library - E-mail a Link - Does Nothing

Tags: document-library

Using SharePoint 2010. User selects the item drop-down list in a document library (hover menu), Send To, E-Mail a Link does not do anything or error. I have tried IE 8 and FF 7. The other options in the Send To seem to work fine. I have Outlook specified as my default email client through the browsers. The issue does not seem to be user-specific.

Any ideas of what to look for? This is my first post so please let me know what additional information would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try adding the below tag between '`<head>.. </head>`' in Master Page.

```
<SharePoint:SPPageManager runat="server"/>
```

Check this post where others have similar issue - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepoint2010general/thread/1e7b2c7b-8d98-4f5b-8b13-de23efbe335d

Comment: Crap, sorry I forgot to turn on email notifications for answers. Thanks for the answer. I checked this out and tried this solution, which got me a little closer. I am thinking there is something going on when we converted from 2007 to 2010 and the core.js got jacked up somehow. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you notice any javascript error when you click that option?
Look below the status bar and see if anything pops up.

Comment: Crap, sorry I forgot to turn on email notifications for answers. There are no js errors. Even watching it in Firefox using the firebug there just doesn't seem to be anything going on with the client-side click event :(  Thanks anyway :)